# asp.net: where to put code to redirect users without a session to the homepage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a web app with loads of pages and most of them require some session variables in order to function.

i want to put some defensive code in my app. where is the best place to put somethign like:

```
if (Session.Count == 0){
                Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
```

EDIT: how do i check if the current page is defult.aspx?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse `Session` with authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quite difficult, yeah fortunately it is solved.

You need to implement **Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute** in **Global.asax**

here is the code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The event occurs just after Initialization of Session, and before Page_Init event
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here it checks if session is reuired, as
        // .aspx requires session, and session should be available there
        // .jpg, or .css doesn't require session so session will be null
        // as .jpg, or .css are also http request in any case
        // even if you implemented URL Rewritter, or custom IHttp Module
        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState
               || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
        {
            // here is your actual code
            // check if session is new one
            // or any of your logic
            if (Session.IsNewSession
                || Session.Count < 1)
            {
                // for instance your login page is default.aspx
                // it should not be redirected if,
                // if the request is for login page (i.e. default.aspx)
                if (!Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("/default.aspx"))
                {
                    // redirect to your login page
                    Context.Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1: Explanation & Conclusion**

As one of the guys told about [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx).

There are plenty of events that occurs.

**Actually events in Global.asax raises in the following sequence**

1. Validate Request                // looks just internal mechanism
2. Perform URL Maping             // looks just internal mechanism
3. Raise the BeginRequest event.
4. Raise the AuthenticateRequest event.
5. Raise the PostAuthenticateRequest event.
6. Raise the AuthorizeRequest event.
7. Raise the PostAuthorizeRequest event.
8. Raise the ResolveRequestCache event.
9. Raise the PostResolveRequestCache event.
10. Just selects a class who implemented IHttpHandler for the application // looks just internal mechanism
11. Raise the PostMapRequestHandler event.
12. Raise the AcquireRequestState event.   **just before raising this event asp.net loads the State like Session**
13. Raise the PostAcquireRequestState event.
14. Raise the PreRequestHandlerExecute event.
15. Call the ProcessRequest method

**Conclusion:** All the events before **AcquireRequestState** event don't have Session object, because Session is not loaded by ASP.Net, so any event from *"AcquireRequestState** event gives Session object therefore this problem solves.
However some checks are required as I mentioned in above code

Answer (score 1):

in the `Application_BeginRequest` of the `Global.asax`

so to summaries the ideas we have:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Session.Count == 0) &&
       !(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("default.aspx",
         StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing to add, make sure you exclude the page where you are redirecting to or you will get a loop

Comment: Session is not available during `Application_BeginRequest`.

Comment: true, put it in Page_Init or any other Page event

Comment: session.count will fail cause session_id is stored there isn't it?

Comment: session id is not stored as session variable, count should be 0 for new sessions

Comment: @K lvanov you are right however as mentioned some more precautions are required

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to have a Page baseclass that performs this check on `Page_Init`. Another method would be to piggy-back off of @K Ivanov's idea with putting it in the `Global.asax`. While Session is not available during `Application_BeginRequest` it should be available in the method `Application_AcquireRequestState`. For not standard web requests, this should provide access to the session to perform what you want.

Comment: I like the base page technique because it is then easy to have it on for some pages and off for others if you so choose. I am personally of the opinion that having it in the global.asax is a bit of a blunt solution unless you really really want to only let one page get hit without session content.

Comment: @Chris - base page is my preferred method as well. I've used it often to achieve similar effects to this.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `Session.Count == 0`, because things like Session_ID are, implicitly, stored in the session.

Preferably look for something like `(Session["UserName"] == null)`, where `Session["UserName"]` is where you, explicitly, store something of the user.

Other than that, Global.asax is the best place ([ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)).

**ALSO**, you have to enter a check that you are not **currently** on ~/default.aspx, because otherwise you will have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your approach.
I don't think it is a good idea to validate globally if certain Session information exists or not. It can get become very messy, very fast. Only certain pages might require specific Session variables, which differ from other pages. Further down the road you might even have some content which can be safely accessed without any existing Session state. Then you will have to start coding exceptions to your rule...

What type of information are you storing in these Session variables? If you elaborate further we could maybe come up with a better approach.