# I want to know everything that happens when a request is recieved by the web server

Tags: asp.net

I want to know everything that happens when a request is recieved by a web server.
Any good articles would help.

I have come across an article but I am not sure if that is everything that needs to be known.
Here is the link.
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article821-beginners-guide-how-iis-process-aspnet-request-.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing **everything** about ASP.NET is a big big task!

Some articles for your endeavour:

- [Securely Implement Request Processing, Filtering, and Content Redirection with HTTP Pipelines in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx)
- [A low-level Look at the ASP.NET Architecture](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)
- [How ASP.NET Web Pages are Processed on the Web Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411013534/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Internals: Request Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetrequestarchitecture.aspx)

but there are tons more out there! Use your good friends Google and/or Bing to help you find those...

Comment: What in the world is ISAPI or ISAPI extension?

Comment: [Wikipedia says this about ISAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Server_Application_Programming_Interface)

Answer (score 1):

Good articles from @marc_s - so I'll try a different tack.  Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or one of the other HTTP traffic monitoring tools as a way of monitoring the data packets.  That would tell you a lot about HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted a similar answer please have a look [asp-net-where-to-put-code-to-redirect-users-without-a-session-to-the-homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899028/asp-net-where-to-put-code-to-redirect-users-without-a-session-to-the-homepage/4899726#4899726)

For quick please check [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)